# Portable way to declare constexpr array from non-type template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, clang

I'm using this approach for a while to do some compile-time c-string manipulations:

```
template<char... args> struct String {static const char data[sizeof...(args)+1];};
template<char... args> constexpr const char String<args...>::data[sizeof...(args)+1] = {args...,'\0'};
```

It works well on all c++11-compliant compilers, however I recently found out that clang does not treat accessing `data` members as a constexpr constants:

```
enum Foo {
    Bar = String<'f','o','o'>::data[1]
    // read of non-constexpr variable 'data' is not allowed in a constant expression (clang)
    // works fine (gcc)
};
```

However, if I rewrite my struct like that:

```
template<char... args> struct String {static constexpr const char data[sizeof...(args)+1] = {args...,'\0'};};
```

It would work on both gcc and clang.

The problem is, 2nd approach works only on c++17, and I'd like to have it at least c++14-compatible. Is there any way?

Also would be nice to find out which compiler is right in this case and why. I've searched for specifications but did not find any reasons why 1st approach should not be constexpr.

Comment: Got your comments! I did an update, maybe it will work now on older compilers also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `static const char` is not `constexpr`! In this case, clang seems to be right here!

If you write it like this:

```
template<char... args> struct String {
   static constexpr char data[sizeof...(args)+1]={args...,'\0'};
};


enum Foo {
    Bar = String<'f','o','o'>::data[1]       
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << Foo::Bar << std::endl;
}
```

It works in C++11 on clang and gcc.

BTW: It makes me wonder why both compilers did not complain about the duplicate definition of `data[]` in that case.

As you are directly initialize your array, there is no need to give the explicit size anymore. So you can simplify to:

```
template<char... args> struct String {static constexpr char data[]{args...,'\0'};};
```

EDIT: As I got your comments, I also tried out older compiler versions and run into the same trouble. But with gcc 7.1 I can compile that version:

```
template<char... args> struct String {static constexpr char data[sizeof...(args)+1]={args...,'\0'};};
template<char... args> constexpr char String<args...>::data[sizeof...(args)+1];
```

In hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. First example compiles on gcc with c++11 and c++14, but fails to link if I'm using `std::cout << String<'f','o','o'>::data`. With c++17 it works as expected. Very strange...

Comment: And on 2nd example clang gives `read of element of array without known bound is not allowed in a constant expression`. gcc can't link it as well.

Comment: Yes, this way it works for me on both gcc and clang, thanks

Comment: @DenisSheremet: Sorry for the late edit here. It is quite hard to remember which c++ standard version implements what and which compiler support it and especially which newer compiler also allows newer features in older standard setting because of "backporting". I recommend to use always the current compiler versions! :-)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have up-to-date compiler on my target and it would be quite painful to update it. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: @DenisSheremet: Typically you can also compile the compiler on the target if it is a "big" host? If not, you may think about cross compile? OK, not longer in scope of the question :-)

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge, a direct initialization of the `constexpr` member would work in C++11 too

```
template<char... args>
struct String {
    static constexpr const char data[sizeof...(args)+1] {args...,'\0'};
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Same problem as in first example from @Klaus answer, gcc fails to link if std is below c++17 and `data` value is used in runtime

Comment: @DenisSheremet Could you please post the exact program that fails to compile? [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/YPcL56) it seems to be fine (I used Klaus's version there, mine is essentially the same).

Comment: I've tried to reproduce my error on godbolt and had no luck. Probably it depends on platform or some versions. Updated answer from @Klaus works for me, but thank you for your time anyway